# Angular 5+ : How to put a delay to a / all HttpClient requests?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this code :

```
this.loading = true;
this.http.get<IUser[]>(Urls.users())
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    this._values = <IUser[]>response;
                    this.root.next({'users': this._values});
                },
                e => console.log(e),
                () => this.loading = false
            );
```

The page which is invoking this code has a spinner, which is showing when 'loading' is set to 'true'. But when the request is completed withing 0.5 seconds the spinner is barely shown, and it looks weird on the page.

How can I make this request wait 1 second before completing (without using setTimeout()) ?

Is there a way to delay all http requests without having to modify every code like the code above ?

Comment: Implement an `HttpInterceptor` and add the delay there using `setTimeout()`. Here: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: My opinion is that you shouldn't delay the actual request for the sake of displaying something on the ui. Those are separate concerns and component calling backend should not be concerned with how its result will be used. On the contrary: you just shouldn't display spinner if the request takes less then 1 second because it will not be perceived by the human as a significant delay. It makes sense to display spinner only if request takes really long time to complete.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov Thanks for the insight. But what if it takes longer than 1 second, say 3-4 ? Then the user (customer in my case) doesn't know and most probably clicks the button again. (I don't like to disable the button, it's an even worse user experience IMHO.)

Comment: @MehmetGunacti - but that's exactly what I suggest: do display spinner - but only if request takes more than 1 second to complete. If it takes less than 1 second then you just don't need spinner at all - it is just not considered as a delay.

Comment: @MehmetGunacti, so diagram is as follows: user clicks button, you start two operations - setTimeout() for 1 sec and http request. If http request is not finished by the time when setTimeout() fires - you show spinner. If request finishes sooner then you just cancel timeout and hide spinner - just in case if it runs in the racing condition on the very edge of the second.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov That makes sense, to only show the spinner after 1 second. I'm still learning Angular and rxjs, so I implemented this through an HttpInterceptor and 'delay'. It's working but the result also looks a bit weird, so I will implement it your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For latest versions of Angular,you can use:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class DelayInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(request);
    return next.handle(request).pipe(delay(5000));
  }
}
```

Ref: Wolf359 answer

Answer (score 49):

Use rxjs/delay:

```
this.http.get(...).delay(500).subscribe(...);
```

In Angular 6+:

```
this.http.get(...).pipe(delay(500)).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I am not able to use this.

Comment: @Karan If you are using Angular 6+, you have to use pipe: `this.http.get(...).pipe(delay(500)).subscribe(...)`

Comment: With Angular 5 I needed `import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';` for this.

Comment: So simple.. so useful for debugging purposes. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I ended up using an HttpInterceptor + delay operator (thanks @Faisal) :
It is the solution to my question, but it's not necessarily the best user experience. Please see @AlexanderLeonov 's comment on this.

```
// ANGULAR
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';

// OBSERVABLES
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

@Injectable()
export class DelayInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log(request);
        return next.handle(request).delay(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### How to delay HTTP request with RXJS

When we use RXJS operator **delay** by itself, it **does not delay** the HTTP request, it delays the output! To delay the HTTP Request, we should wrap the request with another observable and delay that observable. Then, use the **switchMap** to bind the **HTTP Request** observable

```js
import { Observable, delay, of, switchMap } from 'rxjs';

export function delayObservable<T>(obserbable: Observable<T>, duration: number) {
  return of('').pipe(
    delay(duration),
    switchMap(() => obserbable)
  );
}
```

```js
 getDataById$ = httpClient.get('api/product/1');

 const delayedHttpRequest$ = delayObserable(getDataById$, 3000);
```

#### As a Result

When we subscribe **delayedHttpRequest$**, the HTTP request will execute after **3000 miliseconds**.

Answer (score -3):

```
this.loading = true;
const timer = Observable.timer(500); //500 miliseconds
timer.subscribe(t => { 
    this.http.get<IUser[]>(Urls.users())
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    this._values = <IUser[]>response;
                    this.root.next({'users': this._values});
                },
                e => console.log(e),
                () => this.loading = false
            );
});
```