# How to send delayed requests?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a small piece of code where I'm trying to send a request to a server. How do I send this request with a delay of every 3 seconds and stop when all requests have passed?

```
public element: any;
const elements = [];

for (let element of candies) {
   this.element = element;
   requests.push(this.service.getCandy(this.element.user));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5+ : How to put a delay to a / all HttpClient requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107679/angular-5-how-to-put-a-delay-to-a-all-httpclient-requests)

Comment: @JeffreyRam's comment may lead to the usefull `delay` method of RxJs. Try to combine with forkJoin to get notified when all (delayed) observables are finished.

Answer (score 0):

So you have multiple requests and you want to make a delay after each one of them. Most easily you can add 3s delay after each request:

```
from(candies)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(candy => this.service.getCandy(this.element.user).pipe(
      delay(3000),
    ),
  )
```

This obviously means that the delay between two requests is going to be in fact 3000ms + request duration (but maybe this is what you'r going for).

A little more complicated solution is making sure the delay between two requests is at least 3s but at most the request duration.

```
from(candies)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(candy => forkJoin([
      this.service.getCandy(this.element.user),
      timer(3000),
    ]),
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see in the code, I need to add elements to the array. How can this be done here in your example?

Comment: You can collect all emissoons with toArray() if thats what you mean(?).